# What should be the Redirect Url of Snowflake that should be entered in Google cloud Authorized redirect URIs?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions, google-ads-api

I don't know what I have to add as Authorized redirect URIs for Snowflake
I tried this as well  https://<account_identifier>.snowflakecomputing.com/oauth/callback  but didn't worked ,any help?

I tried calling google ads api using snowflake external access integration , this was the flow I have followed:

Created Network rule

```
CREATE OR REPLACE NETWORK RULE Googleadsallow
  MODE = EGRESS
  TYPE = HOST_PORT
  VALUE_LIST = ('googleads.googleapis.com');
```

Created Security integration

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SECURITY INTEGRATION Googleads_outh
  TYPE = api_authentication
  AUTH_TYPE = oauth2
  OAUTH_CLIENT_ID = 'my_client_id'
  OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET = 'my_client_secret'
  OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
  OAUTH_AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth'
  OAUTH_ALLOWED_SCOPES =('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords')
  ENABLED = true;
```

Created Secret with refresh token

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SECRET  Google_ads_secret
    TYPE = oauth2
    OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN = 'my_refresh_token'
    API_AUTHENTICATION=Googleads_outh;
```

I have generated refresh token from Outh2.0 playground by entering scope of Adwords api and used that here.

Created external access integration

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL ACCESS INTEGRATION Google_ads_Integration
  ALLOWED_NETWORK_RULES = (Googleadsallow)
  ALLOWED_AUTHENTICATION_SECRETS = (Google_ads_secret)
  ENABLED = true;
```

Then I have created the function with this definition

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION google_python()
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = 3.8
HANDLER = 'get_translation'
EXTERNAL_ACCESS_INTEGRATIONS = (Google_ads_Integration)
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python','requests')
SECRETS = ('cred' = Google_ads_secret )
AS
$$
import _snowflake
import requests
import json
session = requests.Session()
def get_translation():
  token = _snowflake.get_oauth_access_token('cred')
  url = "https://googleads.googleapis.com/v15/customers:listAccessibleCustomers"
  response = session.post(url, headers = {"Developer-token":"my_developer_token","Authorization": "Bearer " + token,"Login-customer-id":"my_id",})
  return str(response)
$$;
```

This gives me Response 404 ,I tried printing the token from the function and called the api using postman with same token,
by adding postman callback uri https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/browser-callback  in Google cloud Authorized redirect URIs
[image: Google Cloud]
it worked and gave a response, however I don't know what I have to add as Authorized redirect URIs for Snowflake
I tried this as well  https://<account_identifier>.snowflakecomputing.com/oauth/callback  but didn't worked ,any help?